# how to avoid overlaying part of screen when maximizing window

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

thinking about using some sidebar software , but I don't want the sidebar to be overlaid, not overlay other windows.

So how can I configure win7 window manager, so that when I maximize a window, it will not overlay part of screen that reserved for sidebar

or

does some one know about desktop gadget software that prevents self being covered by maximized window?